# SQL to stop at the first match in order to save CPU and memory

Tags: sql, sql-server

My particular case is on Microsoft SQL server but this may be generalized to other databases.

I have a big table named MessageTable, two columns:

```
MessageTime, RawMessage
```

I want to find the latest record that matches pattern "MyPattern".

My current SQL query is:

```
 select top 1 *
 from MessageTable
 where RawMessage like '%MyPattern%'
 order by MessageTime desc
```

The query works but I am not sure about its performance. Does it match through all RawMessage (undesirable) or does it stop once found the first match (desirable)?

If without the "order by" clause, I would assume that the query stops at the first match.

If it is undesirable, is there a better-performance way?

Thank you for your advice.

UPDATE:
(after reading comments and suggestions)
My situation is that we received data from outside. We stored it in the MessageTable (raw table) and in the same time extract information from it and store it in more structured tables. (raw -> structured)

From time to time, we need to search back this raw table, for example, to check whether structured tables got data from the RawMessage correctly. This is where my question coming from. (structured -> raw)

After learning advices from folks in this post, I kind realize we have design problem with our tables. We should probably add a unique MessageId as primary key into the MessageTable. And then add this key as a foreign key to the structured tables. This way, we would avoid a full scan of the MessageTable.

Thank you folks for the suggestions

Comment: Provide the DDL of the table and any indexes on it. Provide the [plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Is your query logically correct without the order by clause? Generally it is not but no one knows your goal. More importantly, don't try to solve a problem you do not have - this sounds like such a case.

Comment: A `top 1` will always stop pulling rows when it gets a match. Question is how it gets that. `like` with a wildcard prefix is not indexable (sargable), therefore perf won't be great because it will just have to keep pulling rows until it gets a match. A covering index on `MessageTime` will at least allow the DB to search in order, so shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: You need to inspect your execution plan to see what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, I am not not a SQL expert. The table is to store raw messages, therefore, if there were an index, the MessageTime would be it. However, I doubt ass MessageTime could be duplicate.

Comment: RawMessage is a huge field, therefore, my goal is trying to limit the number of pattern matching again it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it match through all RawMessage (undesirable) or does it stop once found the first match (desirable)?

The query that you have described has to scan `MessageTable`, because the `LIKE` pattern cannot be optimized (in SQL Server).

If you have an index on `(MessageTime, RawMessage)`, then the optimizer *might* be smart enough to scan the table based on `MessageTime` order and return the first value.  You would need to investigate the query plan to see if this occurred -- it might require that the index be clustered.

If you care about performance, I would focus on fixing the `LIKE` piece of the puzzle.  A full-text index might be a place to look.  Or, if there are a fixed set of patterns in the data, you might want separate columns that "classify" the message.  Those columns can be indexed.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the suggestion. Now I think I have a design issue. (see my update).  Full-text indexing is not an option, as the RawMessage field is huge. (sorry for not being clear on this. I clarified this in my update.)

Comment: @oldpride . . . I don't understand your comment.  A full text index would be much more recommended if `RawMessage` is "huge".

Comment: sorry for my ignorance. I just guess the meaning of full-text indexing. I actually don't know what it is. Let me research. Thank you for pointing this out.